# C# how to get the email addresses that are in a dynamic distribution list

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

I have a C# program that uses Exchange Web Services and it allows me to retrieve key bits of information from Exchange Server for a given mailbox.  Part of this is statistical and I am trying to find the number of people a user sent an email to.

This is being exacerbated by the fact that the user may have sent it to a single address so it appears to have gone to a single recipient but in reality that recipient is an Exchange dynamic distribution list (DDL) which could contain a few or many email recipients.

I need to get all the email addresses that the single DDL contains. Does anyone have code that can do this.  So I just have the DDL name or MessageID and I need to get a list of all the email addresses that represents.

I can currently expand normal distribution lists but the code I am using for that can not expand the DDL type.

Siv

Comment: Does http://www.sghaida.com/c-get-exchange-distribution-and-dynamic-distribution-lists-and-their-members/ help?

Comment: Funnily enough I looked at that before posting my question here and the issue with it is that it assumes you know a lot more about the DDL that I am querying than I do.  My program will just see a user sending an email to an address and it just so happens that address is a DDL.  So all I know is the name/Address, I need to have a routine that can take that name and expand it out to a list of email addresses. I couldn't figure how the routines in that article could do that.

Comment: @mjwills on further scrutiny and a bit of work I was able to get something working using the code in the link you posted.  When I had first looked at it I hadn't twigged that I could use the output from GetDynamicDistributionLists ie the "FILORDN" field of the DistributionList class to provide the "filter" parameter to the listDDLMembers function. So I do now have this working.

Comment: I have created a small test app that allows you to enter in its settings page the Global Catolog server and the domain you are running the app in and it then lists the found DDL's, if you then select that DDL and click another button it will list in a second list all the email addresses that are members of that DDL.  I am having an issue with the two lists sorting alphabetically but once that is fixed and tested I will post the VS project and code to my site so that anyone else who is having issues with DDL coding can download the code and use it in their own project.

Comment: When I have the code tested I will post a link to my downloads page for this project.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? If Yes, please share it as an answer.